# In firebase, how to create a user and add data in user object from ESP 8266?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm working with some IoT projects and for handling all data I have used Blynk application but now I have created my own app but problem is that I want to add sensor data to firebase, but I have multiple users that's why I want to separate my data for every user, how can i do this, which Library is helpful for this? I have searched on Google for this, but everyone adding data in common database but how to separate the data for multiple users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate data per user in your database, you will want to organize the database reference path to a location relevant to the user uid. if your app supports Auth, you can access this with the currentUser object which should have their uid as a property.

Comment: I have created app using flutter and know how to do it in flutter but I don't know about IoT, I want to code in arduino IDE  to send data in firebase for perticular user, so which library is helpful.

Comment: You will want to look at the REST API, store your auth tokens as values, and pass them in requests
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth
and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

Comment: and a decent tutorial on ESP12 web requests https://techtutorialsx.com/2016/07/17/esp8266-http-get-requests/